# running total in crystal reports foe two fields

Tags: crystal-reports

Hai friend s

i am using three colums in the crystal fields credit,debit,netbalance.in net balance i have to total the two fields credit and debit as running total and put in the net balance how to do it.output should come like this:

```
debit      credit     netbalance
------     -----      ----------
-1700.00   0.00      -1700.00
-6250.00   0.00      -8,220.00
 0.00      6250.00    1700.00
 1700.00   2.00       1702.00
```

how to do this in the running total for two fields explain elorabrate in

Answer (score 0):

Make formula, calculating debit+credit and display running total of it. BTW, have you error in last colum? I'd calculate that as:

```
debit      credit     netbalance
-----      ------     ----------
-1700.00     0.00      -1700.00
-6250.00     0.00      -8220.00
    0.00  6250.00      -1700.00
 1700.00     2.00          2.00
```

Comment: You create new formula, calculate debit+credit there and in RT properties select your formula as "field to summarize".